# The value of interpreting $X \supset (X \supset Y)$

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus

In the book *Copi, Irving M. "Symbolic logic." (1954)*, like in many other books, one spots questions such as this:

> If X and Y are false statements, is this statement true?
>   $X \supset (X \supset Y)$

This occurs in an early chapter, where truth tables for propositional connectives are introduced. I have always wondered about the following:

1. It is clear that the answer can be found by examining the truth table of the given compound statement, but is this all the value that the educator expects to be learned from this?
2. Is it expected that the student learns some 'english' reading of such a statement? I ask because this is NOT necessary for solving the exercise. If yes, what would the best reading be? So per example, is it expected that the student tries to prove this for himself 'in english' by thinking: If X then ... If X then Y, hmmm what does this mean? Can I say this in english in a better way? In a way that allows me to answer the question without having to go for a truth table, just like I would be able to do if the statement was $X \land Y$?
3. If the answer to 1. is yes, what other value is one supposed to get out  of this exercise?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just an exercise. The only thing that seems expected to be learned from it is whether you've understood the material so far. I don't see how this would assist in even the slightest way learning an "English reading" of the formula, so your second question seems out of context. Maybe you're asking if a goal of the book as a whole is that one would learn an "English reading" of such a formula(?)

Comment: Falsity implies anything...

Comment: Edited the question to address Derek's comments.

Comment: It looks to me like the edit to the question _entirely ignores_ @Derek's completely correct point.

Comment: Please explain Henning, clearly I am misunderstanding the issue... What is still wrong with question 2., and how is it still out of context? Help me understand.

Comment: Okay, I think I see now what you were trying to do. How I see it, though, is that @Derek actually _answered_ your question (so it should have been an answer rather than a comment). That made it look odd that you're editing the question to ask in more words the question that Derek has _already_ given a correct answer to, but I can see now that his comments does vaguely look like a critique of the wording of the question.